# Gradient of log of norm of a matrix

Tags: derivatives, gradient-descent

I am working on an optimization problem where I need the gradient $\nabla f(X)$ of $f(X) = log(||TX-Y||^2)$, where X is a vector. My attempt is $\nabla f(X) = 
\frac {\nabla  ||TX-Y||^2}{||TX-Y||^2}  = 
\frac {2(TX-Y)^TT}{||TX-Y||^2}$. Am I correct ?